# LINQ to Entities query in "dot notation"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have two entities in my ASP.Net MVC3 application. I am using EF 4.1

```
[Table("tblAccount")]
public class Account
{      
    [Key]
    [Column("Creditor Registry ID", Order = 0)]
    public int CreditRegistryId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("Account No", Order = 1)] 
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }

    [Column("Minimum Installment")]
    public decimal MinimumInstallment { get; set; }

    [Column("Account Status Date")]
    public DateTime AccountStatusDate { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Column("Account Type")]
    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountOwner> AccountOwners { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("tblAccountOwner")]
public class AccountOwner
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    [Column("Creditor Registry ID", Order = 0)]   
    public int CreditorRegistryId { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    [Column("Account No", Order = 1)]           
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Account Owner Registry ID", Order = 2)] 
    public long AccountOwnerRegistryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

I need to convert following query to a LINQ to Entities query using extension method "dot" notation:

```
SELECT Sum(ABS([Minimum Installment])) AS SumOfMonthlyPayments
    FROM tblAccount 
    INNER JOIN tblAccountOwner ON
        tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID] = tblAccountOwner.[Creditor Registry ID] AND
        tblAccount.[Account No] = tblAccountOwner.[Account No] 
    WHERE (tblAccountOwner.[Account Owner Registry ID] = 731752693037116688) AND
          (tblAccount.[Account Type] NOT IN  ('CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04')) AND
          (DATEDIFF(mm, tblAccount.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 4 OR tblAccount.[State Change Date] IS NULL) AND
          (tblAccount.[Account Status ID] <> 999)
```

I tried following query:

```
var minIns = context.Accounts
                    .Where(x=>x.CreditRegistryId == x.AccountOwners.Any(z=>z.AccountOwnerRegistryId)
                    .Sum(p => Math.Abs(p.MinimumInstallment));
```

but it is not working.  How can I write it?

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting as well?

Comment: Missing a bracket after the .Any() statement for one

Comment: either way that any has nothing to do there, as he's comparing an int to a bool...

Comment: Installing and using LINQPad is always a good start

Comment: Isn't the result of the SQL incorrect if is more than one owner for some account?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it matter what form your wrote it in?  Query notation is just as good as the "dot notation."  Anyhow, here's my shot at it.  I believe everything used here should be translatable.

```
var ownerRegId = 731752693037116688L;
var excludeTypes = new[] { 'CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04' };
var maxStateChangeMonth = 4;
var excludeStatusId = 999;

var SumOfMonthlyPayments =
    context.Accounts
           .Join(context.AccountOwners,
                 a => new { CreditorRegistryId = a.CreditRegistryId, a.AccountNo },
                 ao => new { ao.CreditorRegistryId, ao.AccountNo },
                 (a, ao) => new { Account = a, AccountOwner = ao })
           .Where(x => x.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerRegistryID == ownerRegId
                    && !excludeTypes.Contains(x.Account.AccountType)
                    && (x.Account.StateChangeDate == null || x.Account.StateChangeDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month <= maxStateChangeMonth)
                    && x.Account.AccountStatusID != excludeStatusId)
           .Sum(x => Math.Abs(x.Account.MinimumInstallment));
```

And here it is without explicitly using the join:

```
var ownerRegId = 731752693037116688L;
var excludeTypes = new[] { 'CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04' };
var maxStateChangeMonth = 4;
var excludeStatusId = 999;

var SumOfMonthlyPayments =
    context.AccountOwners
           .Where(ao => ao.AccountOwnerRegistryID == ownerRegId
                     && !excludeTypes.Contains(ao.Account.AccountType)
                     && (ao.Account.StateChangeDate == null || ao.Account.StateChangeDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month <= maxStateChangeMonth)
                     && ao.Account.AccountStatusID != excludeStatusId)
           .Sum(ao => Math.Abs(ao.Account.MinimumInstallment));
```

Comment: Hi Jeff: Thanks for the response. Can I do it without join using the navigation property ?

Comment: @Sparrow: Sure it can be written without using join explicitly, though I don't know what you mean by the navigation property.  I just saw "need this SQL-ish query converted to LINQ."  I don't really have too much experience working with EF.

Comment: I mean because these two entities have related properties accountowners has account property and account has accountOwners property. they can access each others columns without join.

Comment: @Sparrow: That I didn't notice.  However I think rewriting it to use that property may be pointless as the query provider will probably write it back to using a join anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ownerRegId = 731752693037116688L;
var excludeTypes = new[]
{ 
    "CA00", "CA01", "CA03", "CA04", "CA02", "PA00", "PA01", "PA02", "PA03", "PA04"
};
var maxStateChangeMonth = 4;
var excludeStatusId = 999;

var SumOfMonthlyPayments = context.AccountOwners
       .Where(ao => ao.AccountOwnerRegistryId == ownerRegId
           && !excludeTypes.Contains(ao.Account.AccountType)
           && (ao.Account.StateChangeDate == null
               || ao.Account.StateChangeDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month <= maxStateChangeMonth)
           && ao.Account.AccountStatusID != excludeStatusId)
        .Sum(ao => Math.Abs(ao.Account.MinimumInstallment));
```

or

```
var SumOfMonthlyPayments =
    (from ao in context.AccountOwners
     let a = ao.Account
     where ao.AccountOwnerRegistryId == ownerRegId
         && !excludeTypes.Contains(a.AccountType)
         && (a.StateChangeDate == null
             || a.StateChangeDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month <= maxStateChangeMonth)
         && a.AccountStatusID != excludeStatusId)
     .Sum(ao => Math.Abs(ao.Account.MinimumInstallment));
```